# The Ionic inAppbrowser screen is blank on IOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, ionic-framework

If I try to build my app for iOS on Ionic in inAppbrowser, remote webpage is a blank screen.
I 'm opening a remote webpage in ionic webview. the main error is occurring here. however, things are working fine in android without any issues.

here is my code
var browser = InAppBrowser.create( wpcDomain + 'checkout/?id='+user.id+'&cookie='+user.cookie+'&add-to-cart='+ _cartIds.join(',') +'&quantity='+ quantity.join(',')+${getIdsForCheckout(variation_ids, 'variation_id')}+'&wpc_mobile_checkout=true', "_blank", InAppBrowserOptions );

```
    if(browser){
        browser.on('loadstop')?.subscribe(event => {
            browser.executeScript({
                code: "if(window.location.href.includes('wpc_mobile_thankyou=true')){  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('wpc-primary'); x[0].addEventListener('click', function(){ window.webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage(JSON.stringify({message: 'fdafda'})) })};"
            },
            function(values) {
            });
        });

        browser.on('loadstart', loadStartCallBack);
        function loadStartCallBack() {

            document.querySelector('body').html("Loading please wait ...");

        }

        browser.on('message')?.subscribe((event) => {
            browser.close();
            browser = undefined;
            router.push('/order-history');
            EmptyCart({dispatch});
        })
    }
```

Here is the issue-

To Native Cordova -> InAppBrowser open InAppBrowser168748626 ["options": [https://demo.cafeapp.com/apps/app/checkout/?id=10&wpc_mobile_checkout=true, _blank, location=no,zoom=no,hideurlbar=yes,closebuttoncaption=Close,clearcache=yes,animated=no]] 2022-12-13 09:52:20.288260+0600 App[16431:563704] Setting the WebView's frame to {{0, 0}, {414, 852}} 2022-12-13 09:52:20.849213+0600 App[16431:563704] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIViewController: 0x140d310f0>.

Comment: I found the solution. it was a URL issue. When I use to encode the URL using encodeURL method problem is fixed.

 let url = encodeURI(URL);